# How to get particular text from the url

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re
url =  "https://hub.atlas.co/3/CDEB98AA-FA21-4C0A-B0AA-BERCI87J/100097"
url_pattern = rf"atlas.co/(\d+)/([^/]+)/(\d+)"
id_search = re.search(url_pattern,url)
print(id_search)
if id_search:
    id = id_search.group(2)
    print(id)
```

Required solution: 100097
The last \d+ for re is not getting. Is there any better solution

Comment: `url.split('/')[-1]`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I need a solution with regex to check with "atlas.co" pattern

Comment: Why don't you use  a url parse then(`urllib.parse.urlparse`)?

Comment: I cannot open the URL. Anyway, it would be better to use BeautifulSoup for parsing web information. You can find more information about it here: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/